# 3G icon won't change with Miui themes

Tags: miui, themes, notification-icons

I recently upgraded my HTC Incredible's Miui ROM version from 11.20 to 20.21 - I flashed the zip from CWM recovery, wiped cache, and wiped dalvik cache. When it booted up the first time everything was great...but after a restart I noticed the 3G icon/indicator in the status bar had changed from the white-themed, stylized 'Miui look' to the Android stock green look. This change seems to have taken place only in the status bar, not in the notification shade.

For example, here is status bar in its normal state now after the ROM update. It's showing the green stock Android 3G icon that I do not like:

[image: Wrong 3G icon]

But when I pull the shade down I see the 3G icon that I do like, the icon that was also showing in the status bar before the change (inverted in color, of course):

[image: Right 3G icon]

I tried reinstalling the ROM update (wiped both caches again) but it hasn't changed back. I also tried using Miui's theme engine to reskin the status bar to no avail. The visual discontinuity is small but annoying - how can I get the proper icon back to the status bar? I'd like to avoid a factory reset if possible.

**Edit**

*I've determined that the icon I'm seeing is in fact the stock 3G icon, the one that would display in a Miui ROM without any themes. What I'm looking for is the icon to change when I apply a new theme in Miui, which it is not. Just like in my pictures, though, it is only the 3G icon in the status bar, not in the status bar when the shade is drawn.*

Comment: I guess they might have forgotten to change the icon in the `framework-res.apk` file or something of that nature. You'd need to pull `/system/framework/framework-res.apk` and extract it to check the drawables.

Comment: I'm assuming this means using adb? I'm a little ashamed to admit I've never given it a try - can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you've got a file explorer that works with root permissions you could just copy it on to your SD card, then move that over to your computer. Otherwise you can try the CyanogenMod wiki's instructions for setting up the SDK/adb: http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Howto:_Install_the_Android_SDK#OS_Specific_Instructions (I think you can ignore the JDK stuff at the top of the page, you shouldn't need it just for adb).

Comment: Finally got a chance to dig into `framework-res.apk` - I found drawables for lots of things (including 4G data icons) but not 3G. Interestingly, I've noticed that while the icons I see in this apk are always the same, even after I change the theme and status bar icons change change in the UI. I'm updating my question to reflect what I've found. Any ideas?

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is to maybe check the drawables in `/system/app/SystemUI.apk` (assuming that exists, I *think* it should on MIUI). I thought the status bar stuff usually lived in `framework-res.apk`, but I could be mistaken. Beyond that I'm at a loss for ideas :-/